# SwingWorker doesnt run doInBackground properly

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

So I got into SwingWorkers to handle my Text manipulating with different Classes and Threads. As shown below, my Swingworker gets a filepath and scans the text, passing the lines to a String. With `getData()` I return the scanned String to my main Class. But this does not work until I run the method `scanFile()`in the Constructor of my Worker Class. **So my Question is:** Why does my SwingWorker Class not run the `doInBackground()` properly?

```
public class ScanWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private File file;
    private String text;

    ScanWorker(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        scanFile();
        return null;        
    }

    public String getData() {
        return text;
    }

    private void scanFile() {
        String line = "";
        try {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                line = scan.nextLine();
                if(!scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    text += line;
                } else {
                    text += line + "\n";    
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not be adding your own `getData()` method for the return value, because this isn't thread-safe. It's precisely what SwingWorker tries to avoid by providing its own mechanism for transferring the result back to the Swing thread. The result type is the first type parameter of the SwingWorker, so instead of `SwingWorker<Void,Void>`, you should have `SwingWorker<String,Void>`.
2. Change `protected Void doInBackground()` to `protected String doInBackground()` (since that is your result type).
3. Remove the `text` field, and instead *return* the result String from `doInBackground()`.
4. After you return the result from the `doInBackground()` method on the worker thread, the [`done()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done--) method will be called on the Swing thread. You're missing that method. From that method you can call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--) to retrieve the result. Add the method as follows:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void done() {
       String result;
       try {
           result = get();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
       // Now do whatever you want with the loaded data:
       ...
   }
   ```
5. SwingWorker doesn't do anything until you start it by calling its [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute--) method. Make sure you're doing that!

P.S. You shouldn't build up the text in a String variable directly, as that recopies the entire string every time you append a line to it, which gives atrocious performance. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for this sort of thing, calling `toString()` on it only at the end.

Or, since there is no point splitting the file to lines if you only want to join them back together again, you can read the full file in one go:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    return new String(
        java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()),
        java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed help! This all makes a bit more sense now. I didn´t know that I have to actually call execute to run the worker in a new thread. I´ll work & play around with this.

Comment: I Just wanted to add, that I played around with this at the weekend and I got a solution, based on your help, that works. I created OOP SwingWorker Classes for my String manipulation and finally they run in their own Threads and my GUI is updated properly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you put `scanFile()` in the constructor, then you executed that method on the current thread, defeating the purpose of `SwingWorker`.

Your *pull*-based approach where you `getData()` from the worker, probably immediatly after you `execute` it, is wrong: you must instead override `done()` and do any work related to the produced results. Alternatively you may use the `publish` and `process` approach where you receive pieces of data in the EDT as they are being produced by the worker thread.

Comment: Thank you. I got away from getting the data with an extra method and I´m using the SwingWorker Class the right way now.